# Using ipad pro and apple pencil as a graphics tablet

Tags: grease-pencil

I have an iPad Pro + Pencil and was wondering if there is any chance to use it as a graphics tablet with blender? I mean drawing on my Ipad and see on my pc monitor. Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn’t be closed ... the linked question isn’t the same question being asked here. Linked question wants to run Blender *on* the iPad. This question wants to use the iPad as an input device.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a solution after doing some research. But, there are possible ways to work around it.

If you have a Mac, then it might be possible to use Sidecar, allowing you to use your iPad with your machine. Unfortunately, I have yet to try it, my machine is too old so it does not support it.

There are also apps that can let your iPad control another computer. While touch is definitely supported, I do not think they will have the pressure detection features of the apple pencil.

Comment: Sidecar works, as does touch via it.

Comment: @troy_s, of course it should, but then problem is that pressure sensitivity might not which is a big reason for using a graphics tablet.

Comment: I think it does?